# Delay in Queueable job execution

Tags: trigger, queueable-interface

I have a Queueable job en queued by a custom trigger and the Queueable job makes REST API call to an external system. When I monitor the job, it used to start processing in couple of minutes but in one occurrence it took ~30 minutes to start its processing. I am unable to replicate this issue.

Can someone shed some light on this? What could be the reasons for the delay?

For me it sounds like one off use case.

Thanks for your inputs!

_Sethuraman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This well worth reading [Asynchronous Processing in Force com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com) documentation makes the point that:

> Force.com asynchronous processing makes a best effort to complete
>   requests as quickly as possible, however there are no guarantees on
>   wait or processing time.

Your asynchronous job is only one of many that are being handled and while the logic does aim to share out the available processing capacity sometimes the load can be much higher than other times and so your job will have to wait longer before it can start.

(The article I linked to in the first paragraph also explains the "extended delay" concept where if a lot of requests are being made from your org extra wait time will be added.)